# Would like some suggestions to clean up a series of if statements

Tags: java, refactoring

I have a method which does quite a lot of validation and it is growing out of hand. I would appreciate any suggestions on how best to clean up this method. I'm using Java 11 and this method is part of a Spring Boot microservice.

```
public void validateRequest(DepositRequest depositRequest, String transferId, String userId) {
    if (!Arrays.asList("REALTIME_PAYMENT", "ACCOUNT_PAYMENT").contains(depositRequest.creditTransfer()
            .getTransferInformation().getValue())) {
        logError(depositRequest, participantUserId, etransferId, INVALID_ACCOUNT_NUMBER);
        throw new ServerValidationException(INVALID_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, PAYMENT);
    }

    if (depositRequest.creditTransfer().getGroupHeader().getSettlementInformation().getClearingSystem() == null) {
        logSchemaValidationError(depositRequest, etransferId, participantUserId, "proprietary");
        throw new ServerValidationException(SCHEMA_VALIDATION_ERROR, PAYMENT);
    }

    if (depositRequest.creditTransfer().getGroupHeader().getInstructing()
            .getInstitutionIdentification().getMemberIdentification() == null) {
        logSchemaValidationError(depositRequest, etransferId, participantUserId, "member_identification");
        throw new ServerValidationException(SCHEMA_VALIDATION_ERROR, PAYMENT);
    }

    if (depositRequest.creditTransfer().getGroupHeader().getInstructed()
            cialInstitutionIdentification().getMemberIdentification() == null) {
        logSchemaValidationError(depositRequest, etransferId, participantUserId, "member_identification");
        throw new ServerValidationException(SCHEMA_VALIDATION_ERROR, PAYMENT);
    }

    if (depositRequest.creditTransfer().getTransferInformation().getCreditor().getName() == null) {
        logSchemaValidationError(depositRequest, etransferId, participantUserId, "creditor.name");
        throw new ServerValidationException(SCHEMA_VALIDATION_ERROR, PAYMENT);
    }

    if (depositRequest.creditTransfer().getTransferInformation().getDebtor().getName() == null) {
        logSchemaValidationError(depositRequest, etransferId, participantUserId, "debtor.name");
        throw new ServerValidationException(SCHEMA_VALIDATION_ERROR, PAYMENT);
    }

    if (depositRequest.authorization() != null) {
        if (depositRequest.authorization().getToken() == null ||
                authorization().getToken().length() < 1 ||
                authorization().getToken().length() > 35) {
        logSchemaValidationError(depositRequest, etransferId, participantUserId, "participant_authorization_token");
        throw new ServerValidationException(SCHEMA_VALIDATION_ERROR, PAYMENT);
        }
    }

    if (!isCreditorAccountIdentificationValid(depositRequest.creditTransfer().getTransferInformation().getIdentification())) {
        logSchemaValidationError(depositRequest, etransferId, participantUserId, "identification");
        throw new ServerValidationException(INVALID_ACCOUNT_INFO, PAYMENT);
    }

    if (!depositRequest.creditTransfer().getTransferInformation().getSettlementDate().equals(LocalDate.now())) {
        logSchemaValidationError(depositRequest, etransferId, participantUserId, "settlement_date");
        throw new ServerValidationException(SCHEMA_VALIDATION_ERROR, PAYMENT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code is good code. Your current code is easy to understand and maintain. So I would not necessarily rush to change it. But if you want, you could:

1. do each validation in a separate private method and just call each method in your main validate method

   ```
   public void validateRequest(DepositRequest depositRequest, String transferId, String userId) {
    validateAccountNumber(depositRequest,transferId, userId);
       ...
   }

   private void validateAccountNumber(DepositRequest depositRequest, String transferId, String userId) {
       ...
   }
   ```

2. you could get fancy and create a Validator interface

   ```
   public interface Validator {
        void validate(DepositRequest depositRequest, String transferId, String userId);
   }

   public class AccountIDValidator implements Validator {
        public void validate(DepositRequest depositRequest, String transferId, String userId){
             ...
         }
    }
   ```

Then you create instances of this interface for each validation, and you put them in a list, so that your validation becomes

```
   List<Validator> validators=Arrays.asList(new AccountIDValidator(),...);

   public void validateRequest(DepositRequest depositRequest, String transferId, String userId) {
       for (Validator v:validators){
          v.validate();
       }
   }
```